# Force case sensitive method calls

Tags: php, apache, yii, phpstorm, case-sensitive

So when I commit my code I have sometimes left in method calls like `CLASSNAME::fooBar`. The way I should be calling it is `Classname::fooBar`. My co worker said he changed something years ago that he cant remember to force his environment to kick him back if he does this. I've also been told that production is case sensitive. My local environment does not care about case sensitivity but I need it to.

I honestly don't care how I solve this but I'd like to stop facepalming everytime I miss this. I'd even accept a solution on the PhpStorm level.

Comment: *My co worker said he changed something years ago that he cant remember to force his environment to kick him back if he does this.* - maybe he switched to Linux? That would solve your problem too. ;)

Comment: You mean this one: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ (EOLed 2 years ago)? Well, that is weird - autolodaing should not work on case-sensitive systems if you use incorrect case in class name.

Comment: For clarification: class names in PHP are case insensitive. The real deal is your file system may be case sensitive and if so, with an autoloading (which keeps these names as is), if the case of the class name in your script doesn't strictly match the one of its file, this autoload won't be able to find your class. For example, if you write `new Foo` but this Foo class is located in the file `foo.php`, on a regular Linux/BSD file system, this won't work, only `new foo` would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm has an inspection for that -- you just need to activate it.

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Inspections
- PHP | Code Smell | Case mismatch in method call or class usage

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome. If there isnt a better solution I'll mark this as the accepted answer. Ideally I'd like more than a warning but this is better than nothing. Thanks!

Comment: @PresleyCobb Change severity to Error then.

Comment: @PresleyCobb BWT - what kind of "other solution" you expect to see? At what level? Classes and methods are case insensitive in PHP, so they will work -- PHP will not warn about that. If class autoloading does not work then PHP will throw "Unknown class" error .. but that's up to autoloader to took for alternative file names... I guess Yii 1.x uses own autoloader and not the one from Composer.

Comment: Yea I did but that only makes an angry red line under the mismatched case. Which is a big step up from nothing but not exactly what I want. I'll take it though if that's the best I can get. Ideally I'd like php/apache to kick me back at runtime with something like "the method doesnt exist".

Comment: 1) You can customize "Error" appearance -- just alter your Color Scheme. 2) You can run that particular inspection on your whole code/desired files and see all problematic places at once. `Code | Run Inspecion by name...` 3) If you sue code completion, it inserts correct method name (as long as you have completed it and not wrote whole thing yourself)

Comment: Ok that works I changed the background color of the error to the color of my frustration. If I miss it now Im just gonna change professions. :D Thank you so much.